# Локаль браузера и JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

> window.navigator.language
>   и
>   navigator.userLanguage

Как повлиять на эти параметры с помощью настроек браузера? Я хочу выводить или русский или английский язык.

Comment: _`navigator.userLanguage`_ - у меня в хроме такого нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это в IE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Свойство `navigator.language` только для чтения, оно возвращает строку, представляющую предпочитаемый пользователем язык, как правило это язык пользовательского интерфейса обозревателя сети.

Свойство `navigator.languages` только для чтения, возвращающее массив `DOMString` показывающее предпочитаемые пользователем языки. В возвращаемом массиве они представлены по предпочтению с наиболее предпочитаемым языком в первую очередь. Значение `navigator.language` это первый элемент в полученном массиве.

Для того, чтобы переопределить, либо повлиять на эти значения можно для обозревателей сети на основе `Chrome` поменять настройки для языка интерфейса тут:

> `chrome://settings/?search=язык%20интерфейса`
>
> либо тут (перетяните нужное мышкой на нужное место):
>
> `chrome://settings/acceptlanguages`

Либо попытаться в используемой операционной системе (не в обозревателе сети) поменять языки. Для `windows 8` это делается по такому пути:

> `Панель управления` > `Все элементы панели управления` > `Язык`

Насколько мне известно эти значения связаны также с языками клавиатуры пользователя.

Смотрите также: [Как изменить navigator.userLanguage в IE11](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a3d78aaf-9f70-4826-954d-19183173c1c3/) (на английском)

Comment: _`на основе Chrome`_, _`opera:...`_ Тут точно ничего не напутано?

Comment: Ну вот у меня хром, он явно подпадает под термин "браузер на основе Chrome", я ввожу в адресную строку `opera://settings/` и в никакие настройки не попадаю.

Comment: @Yaant, поправил. Благо дарю.

Comment: @Yaant, ну так пиши `chrome://settings/` ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy А в Яндекс-браузере, надо, выходит, писать `yandex://setings/`? :)

Comment: @Yaant, в Yandex-*браузере* надо писать `browser://settings/` :D

Comment: @Qwertiy А, логично! :)

Comment: @Yaant, хотя большинство браузеров (но не все) умеют сами редиректить с `chrome://`.

Comment: Не работает. У меня стоит

Languages
Language
English (United States)
Spell check
English (United States)

а выводит

language: "ru-RU"
languages: (3) ["ru-RU", "en-US", "en"]

Comment: @ПавелЖуковский, ответьте мне на 3 вопроса: 1. какие действия вы проводили (опишите все действия)? 2. Какая операционная система у вас? 3. Какой обозреватель сети у вас?

Comment: @ПавелЖуковский, поправил ответ. Добавил `chrome://settings/acceptlanguages` Если вас мой ответ удовлетворил, то пометьте его галочкой.