# Список локалей toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, locale, i18n, локализация

Есть такая функция, как `toLocaleString()`, необходимая для локализации чисел и дат.

```
Number(100000).toLocaleString("ru-RU");
// 100 000
```

Где можно взять полный список локалей, которые эта функция может принять? Список локалей зависит от браузера? Или нет? Если от браузера, то как вывести этот список?

Необходимо сделать для пользователя возможность выбора локали. А для этого необходимо составить список доступных.

Comment: [Локаль браузера и JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/834921)

Comment: @wololo а как это к вопросу относится? Как получить локаль браузера я знаю, а вот где взять список всех поддерживаемых локалей...